# CSS Text Align Bottom of Container

Tags: html, css

I have a header which has a large image floated on one side, and a small paragraph of text on the other side.  I want the paragraph to start at the bottom of the header div. If there were 5 lines in the paragraph, I want the last line to be at the bottom of the header.  I'm having trouble getting the paragraph to align itself down there.

I have something like this:

```html
<div id='header'>

     <img id='logo' />

     <p id='quote'></p>

</div>
```

And the CSS is:

```css
div#header {
    height: 200px;
}

div#header img#logo {
    float: left;
}

p#quote {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: So do you want everything lined up on the left had side, or what?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/danheberden/ymwPe/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="gonnaBeOnTheBottom">
        <p>Hi there!</p>
        <p>I'm on the bottom!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container {
    background: #EEE;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    position:relative;
}
#gonnaBeOnTheBottom {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

by setting `position:relative` on the parent container, you can absolute position elements inside of it :)

Answer (score 19):

A more modern approach would be the usage of **flexbox**, that vastly eases the responsive work afterwards:

- `display:flex` on the container
- `flex-direction: column` will distribute children from top to bottom
- `margin-top: auto` to the element that you want to stick at the bottom, flex will apply all the free space above

```css
#container {
  background: #eaeaea;
  height:180px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#bottom {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    Whatever content
    <div id="bottom">Will stick to bottom</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across a vertically center trick that I was able to adjust to server this purpose:
http://codepen.io/Bushwazi/pen/VYBBmL

```
parent {
  height: 200px;
}
child {
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  display block
}
```

** Need to point out that browser needs to support `CSS3 transform`: http://caniuse.com/#search=transforms

Comment: Your codepen's code (using flexbox) is completely different from this answer, which doesn't work.

Comment: I guess I didn't completely understand the question. I thought the goal was to get the text to `vertical-align` to the bottom of the parent. Hope this is helpful for someone else who ends up here looking for an answer like i did.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in your code. Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<style>


div#header {
height:200px;
}

div#header img#logo {
float:left;
}

.header p {
float:left
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='header'>

     <img id='logo' src="../Pictures/myfarm.PNG" width="220" height="130" />

 <p > ygkgi65iruyrftyhgffhfjgfhgjkhjfjhfjhfyj </p>
  <p > ygkgi65iruyrftyhgffhfjgfhgjkhjfjhfjhfyj </p>
   <p > ygkgi65iruyrftyhgffhfjgfhgjkhjfjhfjhfyj </p>
    <p > ygkgi65iruyrftyhgffhfjgfhgjkhjfjhfjhfyj </p>
     <p > ygkgi65iruyrftyhgffhfjgfhgjkhjfjhfjhfyj </p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```