# Text to Bottom of Div

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to get the content text of a div to the bottom of it?
Here I've prepared an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/JGuP7/

This is the sample hierarchy:

```
<div class="button">Button Label</div>
```

I'm trying to achieve the result without adding additional spans or changing the hierarchy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Three possible solutions, although each has its own caveats.

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JGuP7/6/)**

The first solution relies on `line-height: 220px; vertical-align: bottom;` to align the text with the bottom of the `DIV`. The second solution creates a `:before` psuedo-element that pushes the text to the bottom of the `DIV` (this requires no additional markup). Both solutions will fail in IE7 or earlier, and both will have issues if:

- The font size changes
- The text wraps to a second line
- The size of the containing element changes

The third solution relies on the `display: box;` property, which is a CSS property that is being phased out (more details at [Quick Hits With the Flexible Box Model](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/)). This solution is only supported by Chrome since v4, Firefox since v2, and IE10 beta. However, a new Flexbox standard has been standardized, but browser support is minimal. This solution could be considered "too new" to be used effectively ([html5please.com/#flexbox](http://html5please.com/#flexbox)).

Generally speaking, you should consider a new wrapping element around your text which will allow for `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` to cozy the element to the bottom of the parent element. This has the benefit of growing the child element *upwards* as the font size or text length increases, and is agnostic to the parent container's dimensions. Depending on how mission critical your positioning is to your layout, you could add this new element using Javascript. This probably isn't ideal given the question you've posed, but browser support isn't less than ideal for the more wacky CSS solutions I've listed above :-p

Comment: Thank you for the extremely detailed reply. It seems like I'll be picking the wrap method since it looks like the most solid one to me.
However, one another issue I'm having is that when I use the wrap method, I'm unable to center the text that is sent to the bottom. The wrapper already has text-align:center on it..

Comment: If you're absolutely positioning the wrapper inside the parent element, make sure it's 100% the width of the parent element. Either `width: 100%;` or `left: 0; right: 0;` will achieve that effect. Without specifying dimensions on an absolutely positioned element, the element will try to become the smallest dimensions possible. Then the `text-align: center;` aligns it to that narrow width instead of the width of the parent element. Looking at the wrapper in your browser's DOM inspector will give you a better idea of what's happening :-p

Comment: OH! Just saw your solution!

Answer (score 5):

Another way to to do this would be by using "display: table-cell" and "vertical-align: bottom".

http://jsfiddle.net/JGuP7/1/

```
.button {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: darkred;
    color: white;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I need to use display:block for everything else to work as I wanted.. :(

Comment: If table-cell doesn't work for you then i'd suggest using absolute positioning like @MikeB suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `position:relative` in the container, and use

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```

in the content, you can achieve the desired result.

Your CSS might look like:

```
    .button
    {
        display: block;
        background-color: darkred;
        color: white;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }
    .bottomContent
    {
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

and your HTML:

```
<div class="button"><p class="bottomContent">Button Label</p></div>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403882/css-text-align-bottom-of-container)

Comment: Hey thank you, I'm also aware of this solution, that is why I've mentioned about the hierarchy "I'm trying to achieve the result without adding additional spans or changing the hierarchy."