# Move text to bottom of div to align with image

Tags: html, css

To preface: I've come across a number of other solutions but have had no luck finding one that works. I'm currently using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711647/text-to-bottom-of-div) answer for align my text to the bottom of my divs, but without any luck.

For whatever reason, my `vertical-align: bottom;` property does not affect the css of the page at all. What am I doing wrong here if I want to align the text to the bottom of the image?

index.html

---

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <a href="">What's This?</a>
            </div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" />
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a href="">About</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Modules -->

<!-- Controllers -->

<!-- Services -->

</body>
```

main.css

---

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-color: #FF3B4E;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    height: 125px;
}

.header img {
    margin: 25px 0;
}

.header .pull-left{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 75px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 75px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.header .pull-right {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 75px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 75px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

The reason I have boxes around `pull-left` and `pull-right` is for visual purposes when dealing with this problem. I'll remove the borders once I can get the text to align properly. Thanks for any help!

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rtc498uk/

EDIT: My goal is to get the text to align like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to show how it should look like?

Comment: Just to double check ? Do you want to align the text within the bordered container or move the actual container to the bottom of the page ?

Comment: See my edit to hopefully clear up confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.pull-right a, .pull-left a{
line-height: 1em;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: When added to the css on the fiddle, this didn't seem to change anything

Comment: forgot to add `vertical-align:bottom;`. This should fix it.