# Display Posts from Bottom of Div (CSS)

Tags: css, scroll, chat, output

I'm working on a chat system and wish for the messages to start on the bottom of the screen, rather than the top.

html:

```
<div>

    <p> First post. </p>
    <p> Second post. </p>
    <p> Third post. </p>

</div>
```

css:

```
div {height:300px; width:300px; overflow-y:scroll;}
```

here's an example of what i'm talking about, sorry if i didn't quite explain enough :p

[image: First example is what i currently have, second is what i need.]

Comment: Include what you've tried. I can't see this being any more difficult then appending messages rather than prepending them however.

Comment: im not refering to a backwards order. the order stays the same. I tried vertical-align:bottom thinking it might do it, it didn't.

first is what i have, second is what i need: http://prntscr.com/2syo90

Comment: Oh sorry, I get your meaning now. You just want to know how to position the div at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: You want the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403882/css-text-align-bottom-of-container)